I can't install pyscopg2 on virtual environment Python
I'm trying to install pyscopg2 in the virtual environment python and I got this message:
Collecting pyscopg2
  Using cached pyscopg2-66.0.3.tar.gz (1.2 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyscopg2
  Building wheel for pyscopg2 (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyscopg2 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [49 lines of output]
      C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'readme'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      installing to build\bdist.mingw_x86_64_ucrt\wheel
      running install
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\ismer\Documents\UMG\SEMESTRE III\PROGRA I\TareaFLASK\env\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\ismer\Documents\UMG\SEMESTRE III\PROGRA I\TareaFLASK\env\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\ismer\Documents\UMG\SEMESTRE III\PROGRA I\TareaFLASK\env\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 410, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 395, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 104, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 184, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 200, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 967, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\normal\lib\python3.11\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 403, in run
          self.run_command("install")
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 967, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ismer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fqucn2vk\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 7, in run
      RuntimeError: You are trying to install a stub package pyscopg2. Maybe you are using the wrong pypi? 
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyscopg2
Failed to build pyscopg2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyscopg2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects 

a use the followings commands:
python -m venv env
. env/bin/activate
pip install flask
 pip install psycopg2


Try installing psycopg2-binary instead

I already did that and it didn´t work out

error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2-binary
Failed to build psycopg2-binary
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psycopg2-binary, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
